# как спрятать часть изображения

Tags: html5, css3

[image: Изображение]

Как спрятать ту часть изображения, которая переходит в следующую секцию, чтобы было вот так:

[image: Изображение]

Comment: свойство overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На контейнер с изображением (синий который) повесить

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: да, это именно то, что нужно. не смог удержаться и не сказать спасибо

Comment: @dima, а на галочку слева от ответа нажать?

Comment: да, нуб и опозорился, больше не повториться =)